# A GUI for running set maven commands with parameters?

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber

Full transparency, I really don't know my way around maven. I have created an automated test suite using cucumber, and I run all my tests through maven commands e.g. simplest one is below

`mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.options="--tags '@TestTag'"`

The above, will run all cucumber tests with the tag @TestTag. Parallel runs and everything else is running fine. However, I would love a user interface of sorts where I can pass the tag parameters amongst other items that I have added to the pom as properties (e.g. `-Dnumber.of.devices=2, -Dtype.of.run=fragmented`).

Something like a dropdown that lists all my available tags, a swith to mark it as distributed/fragmented, a dropdown to set the number of devices to run against. At the moment, I'm manually creating each maven command for each run, saving them when neccesary to Intellij configurations. But is there any tool out there that I can just add the parameters I care about, and it will run the command with those parameters added to my `mvn clean verify` command?

Something like

`mvn clean verify -Dnumber.of.devices=<NUMBER_ENTRY> -Dtype.of.run=<FRAGMENTED_OR_DISTRIBUTED> -Dcucumber.options="--tags '<CUCUMBER_TAGS>'"`

I have already taken care of how those properties will determine the type of run I want.

I would have thought there would be something like this that exists, but can't find anything. I'm totally aware that what I'm asking is ridiculous/silly. Anyway, if anyone can point me towards something or offer advice why this isn't a thing, I'd be very much appreciative.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need soo many parameters to run your default setup of tests? It should be `mvn clean verify`...If I correctly see that your defaults in your pom file have not been decided wisely ...What comes into my mind is: Why do you need so different configuration to run your tests? It should always be the same ? Otherwise your build is not reproducible cause it's depends on the parameters you have given ? ...

Comment: I have different setups because sometimes I want to distribute my tests across devices to speed up the run, sometimes I need to run the entire suite on each device, for greater device coverage. Also, I change my tags often. If I want to include login tests, registration tests, run a smoke test, I have tags to indicate that. The number of devices I choose to run varies also, the number of devices I choose indicates the threadCount.

Comment: Thinking Jenkins is the right way to go now though.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins. It was Jenkins. I avoided it because reading about it seemed kind of daunting. But once I set it up, it was pretty easy. I now have all my configs as I want them, looking forward to digging into the million plugins they have available.